# Package without hard dependencies

Tags: typescript

I'm making a package which provides some abstractions based on `IObservable` interface. For that, I need two external classes which act like `Subject<T>` and `BehaviorSubject<T>` from `rxjs`.

At the same time, I don't want to couple my package with `rxjs`, I want to allow other packages which implement those interfaces, to be suitable as well.

I came up with [this solution](https://gist.github.com/rykotovark/5955aa356a849b4d95aab471e69125fc). It works for me, but I wonder can I rely on that behavior of `import` statement?

That's because I thought that `import`'s are hoisted and all are executed asynchronously. What if in some cases `myLibrary` will be imported before `rxjs` and global setup?

***EDIT:***

I've decided to use an `init({Subject, ...other_types})` function and updated the gist in the link. Now a workflow looks like this:

```
import {some_types} from 'some_package'
import {init} from 'myLib'

init(some_types)

// ... now the consumer can import the rest from myLib and use it
```

I still have a question about the order of `import`s, but that's another story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) can help:

- Interface segregation → define your needs in your own interfaces, probably clause to `Subject<T>` and `BehaviorSubject<T>` but just with what you're using.
- Dependency inversion → depend on these abstract types rather than RxJs types. The rest of the application will be decouple from RxJs.
- TypeScript supporting structural typings, if these interfaces are compatible with RxJs types, the second can be used as dependencies in your application. Otherwise, some wrappers are needed.

Using ES6 modules and static imports, all modules will be loaded in the proper order (unless having some weird module loader/bundler configuration). RxJs can't be loaded after `subjects.ts` in the example below *(edited)*:

```js
// -- subjects.ts ----
export interface Subject<T> { /*...*/ }
export interface BehaviorSubject<T> { /*...*/ }

// -- create-subjects.ts ----
import * as rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from './subjects.ts';

// Subject<T> and rx.Subject<T> are compatible
export function createSubject<T>(): Subject<T> {
    return new rx.Subject<T>();
}

// BehaviorSubject<T> and rx.BehaviorSubject<T> are not compatible => wrapper
export function createBehaviorSubject<T>(value: T): BehaviorSubject<T> {
    const wrappee = new rx.BehaviorSubject(value);
    return {
        suscribe: (callback: Function) => wrappee.suscribe(callback),
        /*...*/
    };
}

// -- consumer.ts ----
import { createSubject } from './create-subjects.ts';

const subject = createSubject<string>();
// ...
```

It's now easy to switch to another stream library, just modifying one file: `create-subjects.ts`, provided `XxxSubject` interfaces have been well designed to fit the app custom needs (which is missing in the question so I cannot provide a better example now) and not just a copy of RxJs.

Comment: Thank you, but your example is slightly different from mine. `subjects.ts` file is supposed to be in my package. It can't import `rxjs` as this will violate the SOLID principle. The line with `rxjs` import should be in a consumer's file, not mine. That way he can decide whether to use RxJS or some other library.

Comment: I disagree with you: it respects SOLID because the dependencies (RxJs) are hidden behind custom interfaces. Soon or later, concrete dependencies have to be injected. But yes, `subjects.ts` can be split in 2: interfaces / `createXxx()`. The 2nd parts is just an example of manual DI config. You can do it your own way, with a DI container or in your application `main`/bootstrapping.

Comment: @RyKotovark: to be less confusing, the code example has been reviewed.

Comment: I've slightly modified your example